# Bit Shifting: Shift Count >= Width Of Type

Tags: c, compilation, bit, compiler-warnings, bit-shift

The code below, when compiled, throws a warning caused by line 9:

> warning: shift count >= width of type [-Wshift-count-overflow]

However, line 8 does not throw a similar warning, even though `k == 32` (I believe).  I'm curious why this behavior is occurring?  I am using the `gcc` compiler system.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


int bit_shift(unsigned x, int i){
    int k = i * 8;
    unsigned n = x << k; /* line 8 */
    unsigned m = x << 32; /* line 9 */
    return 0;
} 

int main(){
    bit_shift(0x12345678, 4);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The compiler won't know that `k >= 32` by seeing only the function `bit_shift`. Checking invocation of that may be too much work for the compilers.

Comment: `x << 32` is UB, the range of a shift count is 0-31 only (at least on platforms where `unsigned` is 32 bits)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value of `k` in `bit_shift` is dependent on the parameter `i`.  And because `bit_shift` is not declared `static` it is possible that it could be called from other translation units (read: other source files).

So it can't determine at compile time that this shift will always be a problem.  That is in contrast to the line `unsigned m = x << 32;` which always shifts by an invalid amount.

Comment: Thanks for this quick and great explanation! +1

Comment: Re “So it can't determine at compile time that this shift will always be a problem” Not knowing that something will always be a problem is not grounds for not warning. If you know there **will** be a problem on at least one occasion, you should warn. The actual issue here would be that the compiler does not recognize the problem at all; it does not see there is a problem in any circumstance.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: Though interestingly, if you write `k = 32; n = x << k;`, gcc clearly "knows" that `k` is `32` and it propagates the constant accordingly, but it still doesn't give a warning.  https://godbolt.org/z/5K8aro  Arguably a gcc bug?

Comment: @NateEldredge I am using `gcc`, to confirm (question edited to note this)

Comment: @NateEldredge that is a good observation which cuts to the core of what I am wondering about here.

Answer (score 1):

I think why Line 8 does not throw a warning is because left shifting an unsigned int32 >= 32 bits **is NOT an undefined behavior**.

C standard (N2716, 6.5.7 Bitwise shift operators) says:

> The result of E1 << E2 is E1 left-shifted E2 bit positions; vacated bits are filled with zeros. If E1 has an unsigned type, the value of the result is E1 × 2^E2, reduced modulo one more than the maximum value representable in the result type. If E1 has a signed type and nonnegative value, and E1 × 2^E2 is representable in the result type, then that is the resulting value; otherwise, the behavior is undefined